# Is it possible to customize application icon badge: Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, customization, badge

This may be a foolish question. But I'm asking it because of my curiosity. Is there is any possible way to customize an iOS application icon badge image(as below:)..?

[image]

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with an image please?

Comment: @JamesWebster:done... :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not possible at all. You have to use Default. After the app launch you can show custom badge icon of the UITabbar.

All the best !!!

Answer (score 3):

If you mean the badge number that can be shown on an app icon, in white text over a red circle, then no, it cannot be set to a custom image. You can only control the number that is shown. It is set using the `-[UIApplication setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:]` method, i.e., the `applicationIconBadgeNumber` property on UIApplication:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:99];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a possible solution, instead of using the OS to add a badge, what if you programmatically replace the app icon with a version that has the badge built into it.

You can use libraries such as:
https://github.com/skb1129/react-native-change-icon

The only question is, does anyone know if Apple would have any objections?